# Create User Profile Piece

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I wanted to create a user profile piece, which joins apostrophe-user so that the admin can make public profile for specific users. I know its not recommended but I see this as the only option to have the possibility for people on this side having a public profile and be able to login and edit their profiles. Otherwise the Admin needs to change user profiles for hundreds of people and this would result in a full time job. User register is not necessary now but maybe in the future so my module should be compatible with apsotrophe-signup.

The beginning is pretty straight forward:

```js
// lib/modules/profiles/index.js
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'profile',
  label: 'Profile',
  pluralLabel: 'Profiles',
  slugPrefix: 'profile-',
  addFields: [
    {
        name: '_user',
        label: 'User',
        type: 'joinByOne',
        withType: 'apostrophe-user',
        idField: 'userId',
        withJoins: true
    }
  ]
};
```

This is the pieces widget:

```js
// lib/modules/profiles-widgets/views/widget.html

{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
  <li class="collection-item avatar">

    {{ piece._user.username }}

    {{ piece._user.title }}

    {{ piece._user.firstName }}

    {{ piece._user.lastName }}

    {{ piece._user.email }}

    <img class="circle grey"
      src="{{ apos.attachments.url(piece._user._thumbnail.attachment, { size: data.options.size or 'one-sixth' }) }}"
      srcset="{{ apos.images.srcset(piece._user._thumbnail.attachment) }}"
      sizes="{{ '8vw' }}"
      alt="{{ piece._user._thumbnail.title }}"
    >

    {{ apos.area(piece._user, 'bio', { edit: false }) }}

  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The fields `_thumbnail` and `bio` I added to `apostrophe-user`:

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js
module.exports = {
  beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
      options.addFields = [
        {
          name: '_thumbnail',
          type: 'joinByOne',
          withType: 'apostrophe-image',
          label: 'Profile Picture',
          help: 'Choose profile picture',
          filters: {
            projection: {
              attachment: true,
              description: true,
              title: true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'bio',
          label: 'Biography',
          type: 'area',
          help: 'Choose Biography',
          options: {
            limit: 1,
            widgets: {
              'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                toolbar: [ 'Bold' ],
                controls: {
                  movable: false,
                  cloneable: false,
                  removable: true,
                  position: 'top-right'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ].concat(options.addFields || []);
  }
};
```

When logged in this works, I see all the fields defined in `widget.html`  however if I'm logged out I see nothing. I expected this cause `apostrophe-users` are unpublished by [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288208/apostrophe-pieces-joins-with-users).
I tried to add a `published` field to `apostrophe-user` but this didn't worked out.

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js
...

        {
          type: 'boolean',
          name: 'published',
          label: 'Published',
          def: true,
        },
...
```

What did I made wrong ?

As a second question I would like to know if it is possible to allow the logged in user to edit his own profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for using users as publicly available data in Apostrophe 2. A common workaround is to create a "Profile" piece type or something like that, then add a join to connect it to a user if that helps with organization.

Setting `adminOnly: false` on the users module you could possibly configure permissions directly, but it would make security concerns around users part of your responsibilities.

Update:
Writing `lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js` in a project like this will add the `published` fields back to users:

```js
module.exports = {
  defaultRemoveFields: [],
  defaultRemoveFilters: [],
  defaultRemoveColumns: []
};
```

By default those arrays include `'published'`, hiding the publishing options from the UI.

Once published they will be visible when logged out. Again, make sure to take security implications into account when doing this.

Comment: "hen add a join to connect it to a user" this is exactly what i made. More specifically i just need help to add the published field back to users the way i did it doesn't work. You also say in the documentation i can add it back but that doesn't work, at least not the way i did it. Can you please take a second look at my question again.

Comment: Thx 'defaultRemoveFields' made it for me I wasen't aware of this option and intended from [this](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-users/#apostrophe-users) statement that I need to add them as normal field like shown above. Maybe this is a little bit misleading and could be updated according your explanation.

Comment: Sure. I've PR'd the docs to make that clearer.